# Post build events using relative paths do not work in VS 2013

Tags: .net, batch-file, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

I have a batch file two levels up.

```
..\..\PostBuildEventCopy.bat $(TargetDir) $(TargetName)
```

This batch file copies certain files to a location mentioned in the batch file. I get the below error. It seems to me that VS is not able to find the batch file.

```
Error: '..\..\PostBuildEventCopy.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

But when I mention the full path to the batch file, post build event goes through.

Am I missing something here? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the current directory with a relative path is never not a mistake.  It is just not located where you hope it is, normally it is the build directory (bin\Debug or bin\Release).  But that's a setting that can be changed so that will break your build event again.

Always specify full paths so avoid this kind of lossage.  And always use "double quotes" around paths so spaces in the path name don't byte.  Fix:

```
   "$(ProjectDir)\..\..\PostBuildEventCopy.bat" "$(TargetDir)" "$(TargetName)"
```

Click the Macros button in the Edit popup to see what ${Something} macros you can use.

Comment: Especially the hint for quotes is very important

Answer (score 2):

> is not recognized as an internal or external command

Just means that it doesn't find your `bat` file. And i'm pretty sure that this is the problem! ;) - if you haven't changed your output directory from `.\bin\debug` or `.\bin\release` it means you have to store this file in your project directory. The two levels up gets resolved from the output directory!

<del>Also be sure to add the `start` command before your bat-call.</del>
My postbuild event for 2 levels up looks like this:

```
..\..\test.bat
```

and the `test.bat` is in the root of my project directory.

Comment: I'm sure you are right with the guess about the main problem. But I can't see any good reason for using `start` here, as normally you don't want that the batch file will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: @jeb & sundar your right - start isn't really usefull here... (asynchronously) i correct the answer